# nutch running on EMR

Tags: nutch, amazon-emr

Can somebody please guide me into the right direction.  I'm trying to get Nutch working on Amazon EMR.  So far, I can get nutch running locally and getting it launched using the shell scripts that come with it.

However, on Amazon, I need to specify a JAR location and options.  I can get the jar by compiling it myself.  However, I don't know where to start as far as the startup options are concerned.

Additionally, what is the main difference between the 1.x and Nutch 2.0.  Is one recommended on EMR over the other?

Answer (score 0):

In case you're still looking for an answer:

When you build Nutch, you will see a job jar in the deploy directory, upload this to S3 and reference that as you're custom Jar while setting up the EMR job flow.

You can then add steps and mention the main class for example: `org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl` and the arguments that you would want. This doesn't change from the way it works in the `local` mode. For example: `urls -dir myCrawl -threads 10 -depth 5 -topN 1000`.

You can get to know what main class to use by looking at the `bin/nutch` script if you intend to use something other than Crawl.java.

Comment: Sorry I didn't address you're second question above. I would prefer using 1.x on EMR so that I can move the crawlDb back to S3, if you have a NoSQL setup on a different box to use 2.x that could become a performance bottleneck.